# Change the color of the table row based on the value from servlet

Tags: css, jsp, servlets, html-table

```css
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;border-color:#999;}
.tg td{font-size:12px;padding:3px 13px 3px 13px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#999;color:#444;background-color:#fff}
.tg th{font-size:12px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px 10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#999;color:#fff;background-color:#deb6db}
tr:hover td.tg-5hgy {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;  
}
```

```html
<%

int total = dao.count();
ArrayList<VO> alist = dao.getMemberList();
int size = alist.size(); 
int size2 = size;

final int ROWSIZE = 20;
final int BLOCK = 5;


int pg = 1;

if(request.getParameter("pg")!=null) {
 pg = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pg"));
}

int end = (pg*ROWSIZE);

int allPage = 0;

int startPage = ((pg-1)/BLOCK*BLOCK)+1;
int endPage = ((pg-1)/BLOCK*BLOCK)+BLOCK;

allPage = (int)Math.ceil(total/(double)ROWSIZE);

if(endPage > allPage) {
 endPage = allPage;
}

size2 -=end;
if(size2 < 0) {
 end = size;
}

%>

<table class="tg" align="center">

 <tr >
     <th class="tg-031e">aaa</th>
     <th class="tg-031e">bbb </th>
     <th class="tg-031e">ccc</th>    

   </tr>     
   <%
  if (total == 0) {
 %>      
  <tr>
   <td colspan="13" style="text-align:center">No have contents.</td>
  </tr>     
     <%
  } else { 
    for (int i = ROWSIZE * (pg - 1); i < end; i++) {
     VO vo = alist.get(i);     
     int idx = vo.getNum();
     String colorValue="#ffffff";
     application.log(vo.getLevel()+"");
      if(vo.getLevel() == 30 ) {  
      colorValue = "#d0c1d0";      
     }else{
      colorValue = "#ffffff";  
     }%>
      <style>      
     .tg .tg-5hgy{vertical-align: middle;background-color:<%=colorValue%>;text-align:center}
     </style> 
 
 <tr>
    <td class="tg-5hgy"  id="num">
    <%=vo.getNum();%>
    </td>
    <td class="tg-5hgy"  id="level">
    <%=vo.getLevel();%>
    </td>
    <td class="tg-5hgy"  id="time">
    <%=vo.getTime();%>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I wanted to changed row background-color of table, when if "vo.getlevel() == 30"
then to "#d0c1d0", but I failed...vo.getlevel() function take value from mysql database, I already checked value by application.log() function, 
how can I solve this problem?

Comment: In what way does it fail? We can't see your database, so we can't tell what goes wrong. Does getLevel() simply never return 30? Do you get a compiler error? A runtime error? Etc.

Comment: Anyway, you have more `{` than `}`; I would look into that.

Comment: vo.getlevel() is just integer variable, for example, we can get number 1~30...

Comment: just i want change row background-color of table.... if vo.getlevel() == 30 then #d0c1d0, if vo.getlevel() < 30 then #ffffff...but continue become all same color..

Comment: All I can say is look into the `{` `}` mismatch issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it..
For example, 
I put <%=colorValue %> in each all td tag

```html
<td class="tg-5hgy"  id="num" style="background-color:<%=colorValue %>">
<td class="tg-5hgy"  id="level" style="background-color:<%=colorValue %>">
```